# Gradle not resolving dependencies from private Nexus 3 repository

Tags: java, gradle, dependencies, nexus, nexus3

I'm trying to build a gradle project the uses a library from a private Nexus repository.

Versions:

- Gradle 7.4
- Nexus OSS 3.37

This is the `build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group 'io.riccardopedrielli'
version '1.0.0'

repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://nexus.riccardopedrielli.io/repository/maven-releases/'
        credentials {
            username '<myuser>'
            password '<mypass>'
        }
    }
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'io.riccardopedrielli.mylib:1.0.0'
}
```

When I run `./gradlew build` I get the following error:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
   > Could not find io.riccardopedrielli.mylib:1.0.0:.
     Required by:
         project :
```

Adding `--debug` i see these lines related to the lib:

```
[org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.builder.NodeState] dependency: io.riccardopedrielli.mylib:1.0.0 from-conf: implementation to-conf: null is filtered.
[org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.builder.NodeState] dependency: io.riccardopedrielli.mylib:1.0.0 from-conf: implementation to-conf: null is filtered.
[org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.builder.NodeState] dependency: io.riccardopedrielli.mylib:1.0.0 from-conf: implementation to-conf: null is filtered.
[org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver] Attempting to resolve component for io.riccardopedrielli.mylib:1.0.0: using repositories [maven, MavenRepo]
[org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.CachingModuleComponentRepository] Detected non-existence of module 'io.riccardopedrielli.mylib:1.0.0:' in resolver cache 'maven'
[org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.CachingModuleComponentRepository] Detected non-existence of module 'io.riccardopedrielli.mylib:1.0.0:' in resolver cache 'MavenRepo'
[org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolver] No meta-data file or artifact found for module 'io.riccardopedrielli.mylib:1.0.0:' in repository 'maven'.
[org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.modulecache.PersistentModuleMetadataCache] Recording absence of module descriptor in cache: io.riccardopedrielli.mylib:1.0.0: [changing = false]
[org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolver] No meta-data file or artifact found for module 'io.riccardopedrielli.mylib:1.0.0:' in repository 'MavenRepo'.
[org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.modulecache.PersistentModuleMetadataCache] Recording absence of module descriptor in cache: io.riccardopedrielli.mylib:1.0.0: [changing = false]
```

Instead, if I use maven with the following `pom.xml`, everything works fine:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>io.riccardopedrielli</groupId>
    <artifactId>myapp</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.riccardopedrielli</groupId>
            <artifactId>mylib</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>localNexus</id>
            <url>https://nexus.riccardopedrielli.io/repository/maven-releases/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <build>
        ...
    </build>

    <properties>
        ...
    </properties>
</project>
```

Since the Nexus repository is ok with maven, I think I'm missing something in `build.gradle`.

Comment: Hi! Have you resolved the issue? I'm having exactly the same trouble.

Comment: @ASten sadly not, I had to switch to Artifactory.

Comment: I'm also facing the same problem, any fix available for gradle?

Answer (score 1):

Try by adding **metadataSources** inside maven, as shown in the example below:

```
maven {
   url = uri("nexus-maven-url")
    metadataSources
    {
        mavenPom();
        artifact()
    }
   }
}
```